# How to use an external js-File in Nodejs, ExpressJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I started today with NodeJS, ExpressJS, Android, to create a little Webapplication. And I faced a problem an it holds me the whole day!

ENV:

Server: `NodeJS`, `ExpressJS`

Client: `HTML`,`Angular`, `CSS`

I try to load the CSS and the JavaScript file from the node_modules folder. But it doesn't work. It works just with the online sources

**works**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/javascript/test.js"></script>
```

**doesn't work**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/javascript/test.js"></script>
```

The server write all the time a 404 Error

[image]

I've tried with absolut and relativ path.
I've tried also with serveral sugesstions from other stackoverflow posts. without a result.

The Servercode was created by Eclipse IDE with 'Express JS Project'

**app.js**

```
    var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')

    ,pageX = require('./routes/pageX');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/pageX', function(req,res){
    console.log("TEST - PageX");
    res.send(pageX.pageX(req, res));
});
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Michael

Comment: can you try changing `http.createServer(app).listen(...)` with `app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Listening to port: ' + port);
});`

Comment: this is snippet from my working source code `'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var config = require('./config');

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('%s %s', req.method, req.url);
    next();
});
app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));

app.listen(config.port, function(){
    console.log('Listening to port ' + config.port);    
});`

Comment: @GurbakhshishSingh : thank your for the fast response, it doesen't work. when I try to call a funcion in the public folder i get an 500 error all the time. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), when using this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

> Express looks up the files relative to the static directory, so the name of the static directory is not part of the URL.

So, to load your `test.js` you should use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/test.js"></script>
```

Also, it means that you should have a `public` directory under `__dirname`.

If I understood you correctly and from what you said you've tried so far, you are running `node` from inside the `node_modules` and you have the following directory structure:

```
app-root-directory/
    public/
    node_modules/
```

I'm quite new to node as well and I believe you're not supposed to be running from inside `node_modules`. But if you are then `path.join(__dirname, 'public')` is not what you want as it will point to `public` inside `node_modules`.

So you also have to change the root directory of `express.static` to `../public`:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one. Worked on my end.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/public/js'));
```