# How to include google maps api in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps

I want to access the google maps api though node because google's best security practices say the api key should be kept hidden.

However, all of the api usage examples use

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

so to access the google api like so

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
```

I want to make calls similar to the one above but through node. How do I include the google maps api in my node project? I know there is a npm googlemaps package which wraps the google maps api but it isn't as flexible as the original google maps api. How do I include an external src file in node?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57216131/3407629 follow this answer

Answer (score 0):

This [Github](https://github.com/moshen/node-googlemaps) will show you on how to use Google Maps API for Node.js

Here is a sample code on how to use this.

```
var publicConfig = {
key: '<YOUR-KEY>',
stagger_time: 1000, // for elevationPath
encode_polylines: false,
secure: true, // use https
proxy: 'http://127.0.0.1:9999' // optional, set a proxy for HTTP requests
};
var gmAPI = new GoogleMapsAPI(publicConfig);

// or in case you are using Google Maps for Work
var enterpriseConfig = {
google_client_id: '<YOUR-CLIENT-ID>', // to use Google Maps for Work
google_private_key: '<YOUR-PRIVATE-KEY>', // to use Google Maps for Work
google_channel: '<YOUR-CHANNEL>' // to use Google Maps for Work application usage tracking
stagger_time: 1000, // for elevationPath
encode_polylines: false,
secure: true, // use https
proxy: 'http://127.0.0.1:9999' // optional, set a proxy for HTTP requests
};
var gmAPI = new GoogleMapsAPI(enterpriseConfig);

// geocode API
var geocodeParams = {
"address": "121, Curtain Road, EC2A 3AD, London UK",
"components": "components=country:GB",
"bounds": "55,-1|54,1",
"language": "en",
"region": "uk"
};

gmAPI.geocode(geocodeParams, function(err, result){
console.log(result);
});

// reverse geocode API
var reverseGeocodeParams = {
"latlng": "51.1245,-0.0523",
"result_type": "postal_code",
"language": "en",
"location_type": "APPROXIMATE"
};

gmAPI.reverseGeocode(reverseGeocodeParams, function(err, result){
console.log(result);
});
```

It also shows how to use Node.js in Statics Maps, Streetview and other Google Maps API Web Services.

For the external scr file in node, I think this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618403/how-to-use-an-external-js-file-in-nodejs-expressjs) can help you with that.